# How to connect backend to frontend in java?

Tags: java, html, frontend, backend

I'm trying to connect a backend program that I wrote in java to frontend design that I made with "FIGMA". I pretty new in that, I was trying to read some information about it but didn't successes.
how could I make this connection. its kind of a form application that i want to link it to HTML design

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671420/how-do-you-connect-java-backend-with-html-css-frontend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you connect Java backend with html/css frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671420/how-do-you-connect-java-backend-with-html-css-frontend)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to connect backend and frontend, one way is to use `REST` protocol.

[image]

Your `Backend` can expose `REST` service (some library you can use are Spring MVC, Jersey, CXF, etc) then your `Frontend` can call the `REST` service.